# Css 3 column div layout, left and right are fixed, middle needs to be 100%

Tags: css

I need to create a css 3 column div layout that is 100% of the width of the screen, where the left column is 100px, the right column is 100px and the middle column fills the remainder of the width. Text in the middle div must not overflow.

I've had a look at other questions and haven't been able to come up with this solution. How would I do this?

Edit:
This is what I was working on. I mistakenly thought it was too trivial to need further explanation:

```
<div style="width: 100%; ">
    <div style="display: block; height: 20px; float: left;width:100px">
           Test1
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; height: 20px;float:left;width:100px">
       Test3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)? Where is your [**existing code**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Please review [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: We cant help you unless you post your code

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy.

Use **css calc()** and say that the middle is `calc(100% - 200px)` and just add `overflow: hidden;`

***UPDATE:***

If this does not work you can make main div with full width of **100vw or 100%**.

And make it `position:relative; padding: 0 100px;` and there goes the main  div and for those on sides:

**For left use:**

```
position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 100px;
```

**For right use:**

```
 position: absolute; top:0; right:0; width: 100px;
```

Comment: my final solution was <div style="width:100%">
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;overflow:hidden">Test1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:calc(100% - 210px);overflow:hidden">
    Test2
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:100px;overflow:hidden">Test3</div>
</div>

Comment: this one was preferable because it goes back to IE9

Comment: If you type css calc() into google and find one of the css sites such as w3schools, scroll down and they have a compatibility grid that says it works in ie9. I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: I can confirm that this approach works in ie11. The grid-template-columns version failed in IE11.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="thing">
<div>thing</div>
<div>thing</div>
<div>thing</div>
</div>

div.thing {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 100px auto 100px;
justify-items: center;
}

div.thing:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: 1;
}

div.thing:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 2;
}

div.thing:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 3;
}
```

https://codepen.io/fencepencil/pen/qojXQQ

Comment: any idea how far back this works? I think I need to support IE9